# Create one-time subscription

Tags: rxjs

I need to create a subscription to an `Observable` that is immediately disposed of when it is first called.

Is there something like:

```
observable.subscribeOnce(func);
```

My use case, I am creating a subscription in an express route handler and the subscription is being called multiple times per request.

Answer (score 426, accepted):

Not 100% certain about what you need, but if you only want to observe the first value, then use either `first()` or `take(1)`:

```
observable.first().subscribe(func);
```

note: `.take(1)` and `.first()` both unsubscribe automatically when their condition is met

## Update from RxJS 5.5+

From comment by [Coderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007777/create-one-time-subscription/28030416#comment91800031_28030416).

```js
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'
    
observable
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(func);
```

[Here's why](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/22c6137116268af91fafa14cc89d5db4f234bec3/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why)

Comment: Does the subscription get automatically cleaned up after?

Comment: Yes it does. Take and first both unsubscribe when their condition is met.

Comment: Why doesn't the documentation say that it automatically disposes of the subscription?

Comment: It's a general RxJS rule that subscriptions are disposed when an observable stream ends.  That means any operator that "shortens" a stream (or transforms it into a different type of stream) will unsubscribe from the source stream when their operation completes.  I'm not sure where or if this is stated in the documentation.

Comment: @Brandon what about if the first value never gets returned, will it cause memory leakage? Is it best to also have an unmount function that will unsubscribe/dispose the observable?

Comment: @Beastwood yes if you subscribe when a component is mounted, then you want to be sure to unsubscribe when the component is unmounted to prevent resource leaks

Comment: for some weird reason first() doesn't work for me, but take(1) does ...

Comment: `first`? surely `last` or `pop` is what our brains want to hear

Comment: If anybody is coming to this in 2018, you actually want `observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(func)`, where `first` comes from `rxjs/operators`.

Comment: @Coderer What is the difference?

Comment: [here's why](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why)

Comment: [Here's why](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/pipeable-operators.md#why) link as of May 2020.

Comment: The link is still broken

Comment: `observable.pipe(first())` didn't work for me (RxJS 5.5); `observable.first()` did work.

Answer (score 37):

RxJS has some of the best documentation I've ever come across.  Following the bellow link will take you to an exceedingly helpful table mapping use cases to operators.  For instance, under the "I want to take the first value" use case are three operators: `first`, `firstOrDefault`, and `sample`.

Note, if an observable sequence completes with no notifications, then the `first` operator notifies subscribers with an error while the `firstOrDefault` operator provides a default value to subscribers.

[operator use case lookup](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/which-instance.md)

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE(DEC/2021):**

As `toPromise()` function has been deprecated in RxJS 7, new functions have been announced to be used instead of it. `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom`.

`firsValueFrom` function resolves the first emitted value and directly unsubscribe from the resource. It rejects with an [EmptyError](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/EmptyError) when the Observable completes without emitting any value.

On the other hand, `lastValueFrom` function is, to a certain degree, same to `toPromise()` as it resolves the last value emitted when the observable completes. However, if the observable doesn't emit any value, it will reject with an [EmptyError](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/EmptyError). Unlike `toPromise()` which resolve `undefined` when no value emits.

For more information, please check the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise).

---

**Old Answer:**

If you want to call an Observable only one time, it means you are not going to wait for a stream from it. So using `toPromise()` instead of `subscribe()` would be enough in your case as `toPromise()` doesn't need unsubscription.

Comment: very interesting, this also mean we can just `await` the `promise` which makes it one liner

Comment: @LouieAlmeda could you give us a one liner example ?

Comment: Hi @AdoRen, I've expounded the technique in an answer here for you, I hope that helps.

Comment: `toPromise()` is more like `observable.pipe(last())` than like `first()`.

Comment: yes trhe "promise" answer would be: `await observable.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()`

Answer (score 3):

To supplement [@Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28030416/493807), using `first()` or the like is also essential for updating a `BehaviorSubject` based on its `Observable`. For example (untested):

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject({1:'apple',2:'banana'});
var observable = subject.asObservable();

observable
  .pipe(
    first(), // <-- Ensures no stack overflow
    flatMap(function(obj) {
      obj[3] = 'pear';
      return of(obj);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(function(obj) {
    subject.next(obj);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clean and Convenient Version

Expanding on M Fuat NUROĞLU's amazing answer on converting the observable to a promise, here's the very convenient version of it.

```js
const value = await observable.toPromise();

console.log(value)
```

The beauty of this is that we can use that value like a normal variable without introducing another nested block!

This is especially handy when you need to get multiple values from multiple observables. Neat and clean.

```js
const content = await contentObservable.toPromise();
const isAuthenticated = await isAuthenticatedObservable.toPromise();

if(isAuthenticated){
   service.foo(content)
}
```

Of course, you will have to make your containing function `async` if you are to go with this route. You can also just `.then` the promise if you don't want the containing function to be async

I'm not sure if there are tradeoffs with this approach, feel free to let me know in the comments so we are aware.

P.S. If you liked this answer, don't forget to upvote M Fuat NUROĞLU's Answer as well :)

Comment: Please be aware that the Promise is not resolving until the underlying Observable has completed. So if `.toPromise()` is not working, check that your Observable is getting completed.

For example a "take(1)" could help: `const value = await observable.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()`

See this comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2536#issuecomment-306041463

Answer (score 2):

I had similar question.

Below was called even later on from different state changers. As I did not want to.

```js
function foo() {
    // this was called many times which was not needed
    observable.subscribe(func);
    changeObservableState("new value");
}
```

I decided to try `unsubscribe()` after subscribe as below.

```js
function foo() {
    // this was called ONE TIME
    observable.subscribe(func).unsubscribe();
    changeObservableState("new value");
}
```

`subscribe(func).unsubscribe();` is like `subscribeOnce(func)`.

I hope that helped you too.

Answer (score 1):

observable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe() use take 1 it subscribe for one time then exit

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.