# Angular Binding to a function on the view results to infinite calls to the data service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I'm trying to bind a `src` attribute of images inside an `ngFor` directive that looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="imageId of imageIds">
  <img [attr.src]="imageSrc(imageId)" alt="{{imageId}}">
</div>
```

the `imageSrc` method inside the component looks like this:

```
imageSrc(imageId: string){
  var hostUrl = "http://192.168.0.101:3000/";
  var imageUrl = hostUrl+"images/"+imageId;
  var imgSrc = "";

  this._imageService.getImage(imageId)
  .subscribe(image => {
    imgSrc = hostUrl + image.url
   });
  return imgSrc;
}
```

The `getImage` function in the `Injectable` `ImageService` looks like this:

```
getImage(id: string) {
  var _imageUrl = "http://192.168.0.101:3000/images/"+id;
  return this.http.get(_imageUrl)
  .map(res => <Image>res.json().data)
  .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

The problem is, with only two `imageIds` the `*ngFor` directive renders the two list items as expected (but no images displayed) but the call to the data service doesn't stop, it gets the two images over and over on what appears to be an infinite loop until the application crashes. what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is related to `*ngFor`. If you bind from the view to a function then this function is called every time Angular runs change detection which is by default on every event that happens on your page.

In `devMode` (in contrary to `prodMode`) change detection even runs twice for each event.

Store the result in a property and bind to that property instead or at least return a cached result from your function on subsequent calls if the input parameter (`id:string`) hasn't changed since the last call.

For example like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36291681/217408

Comment: So I assume its not a good idea to bind to a getter then either?

Comment: A getter might be OK if it doesn't do any expensive work like `get fullName():string { return this.givenName + ' ' + this.familyName; }`. But change detection is extremely efficient with fields, therefore it would be better to implement `givenName` and `familyName` as getter+setter where `fullName` is updated every time the setter is called. An absolute no-go is a getter like `get style() { return {'background-color': 'red'}; }`, because here every time change detection runs, a new object instance will be returned (you should even get an exception in development mode), ...

Comment: ... and also don't do any kind of more expensive work than above string concatenation.