# How to return an observable from a http service in angular2

Tags: http, angular

Unfortunately as I was storing many results on the service, I'm now stuck with many `{{myservice.somevalue}}` (and `myservice.someother`) etc. sprinkled over my other components.

I believe it would be nicer to return from the service to a component.

This is the code that I have on the service:

```
getIssue(issueName: string) {
    return this.http.post(this.URL + 'issue/all', JSON.stringify({'issueName': issueName}))
                    .subscribe(data => this.somevalue = data.json(),
                                err => console.log(err));
}
```

So then on several other components I call functions like `this.myservice.getIssue(issueName)`.

In the HTML I'd prefer to use `{{somevalue}}`.

What can I do to return a http observable from the http service?

Comment: It's kinda unclear what do you want to do ? **return this.http.post(....)** is already an **Observable**. So you do return an Observable from the http service  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @tibs I completely agree it sounds silly. Unfortunately I'm not really sure how to describe what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeService {
  someValue = new BehaviorSubject();

  getIssue(issueName: string) {
      return this.http.post(this.URL + 'issue/all', JSON.stringify({'issueName': issueName}))
                      .subscribe(data => this.somevalue.next(data.json()),
                                  err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

In your component

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(someService:SomeService) {
    someService.someValue.subscribe(val => {
      this.someValue = val;
    });
  }
}
```

For an alternative approach see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36291681/217408

Comment: That `this.somevalue.next` is new. How does that work? And what is `BehaviorSubject`, where does it come from?

Comment: Does this not introduce overhead; it seems like more work is done?

Comment: This is very cheap in relation to for example a DOM manipulation or even a server call.

Comment: So does this solve the problem I think I'm having; is it a good practice?

Comment: Basically yes. It might vary slightly depending on the actual use case. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/36291681/217408

Comment: Would it also be possible to `return this.http.post(...)` and then in the component do the subscribe `this.myservice.getIssue("").subscribe()` ?