# Angular2, Using the main component's onInit to call services

Tags: angular

I was wondering how exactly works the onInit, especially when calling some services. Here is my main component :

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "app/app.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig(){
...
}
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private _fooManager: FooManager) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._fooManager.fetchAllFoos() // Do a web service call to fetch some data and store them inside the FooManager
    }
}
```

(`FooManager`'s injection comes from my bootstrap.ts)

then all my other components are using the FooManager's data (especially in their templates). I was wondering if I had to check the status of the call done in the `fetchAllFoos` or if the `ngOnInit` gives any guarantees that the values are fully loaded ?

If not, I guess one solution would be to give a promise back and then check the promise status.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnInit()` doesn't do anything special except being called at some point after the component was initialized.

What you want is probably something like [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)