# (Ionic 2) Getting data from php services is undefined

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am new in ionic 2 and try to get my data from php services that i have created for ionic 1. It is works on ionic 1 but when i am getting data from ionic 2 it is undefined. It is works when i am getting data from php server on some website (from tutorial) but when getting my data from my local host it is undefined. It is the problem in my php code or i need to change my services. Thanks...

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        $db_name  = 'kuliner';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';


        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);


        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM promo';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();


        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );


        $json = json_encode( $result );
        echo $json;     
?>
```

Here is my services:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the PromoService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class PromoService {
  data: any = null;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // We're using Angular Http provider to request the data,
      // then on the response it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
      this.http.get('http://localhost:9999/KY Mobile/Promo/selectPromo.php')
        .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data.results;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My home page:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {PromoService} from '../../providers/promo-service/promo-service';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers: [PromoService]
})
export class Home {

  public promos: any;  
  constructor(public promoService : PromoService) {
    this.loadPromo();
  };

  loadPromo(){
  this.promoService.load()
  .then(data => {
    this.promos = data;
    console.log("ABCD" + data);
  });
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<ion-content padding class="page1">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let promo of promos">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{promo.image}}">
      </ion-avatar>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Update:
Solved now, the code must be this.data = data in PromoService. Thanks..

Comment: what and where is undefined? can you debug the load() method to identify the point where it's failing?

Comment: in res , the res give undefined

Comment: can you share the http get you do in ionic 1 that is working?

Comment: You mean `res` in `this.http.get('http://localhost:9999/KY Mobile/Promo/selectPromo.php')
        .map(res => res.json())` is `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `res` in

```
 this.http.get('http://localhost:9999/KY Mobile/Promo/selectPromo.php')
    .map(res => res.json())
```

is `undefined` then you don't get a value from `http.get()`

**Other suggestions**

You can use `toPromise` like

```
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:9999/KY Mobile/Promo/selectPromo.php')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .do(data => this.data = data.results);
  .toPromise();
```

or just return the promise returned from `http.get()` and subscribe on the call site

```
load() {
  if (this.data) {
    // already loaded data
    return Observable.of(this.data);
  }
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:9999/KY Mobile/Promo/selectPromo.php')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .do(data => this.data = data.results);
}
```

and then just use `subscribe()` instead of `then()`

```
loadPromo(){
  this.promoService.load()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.promos = data;
    console.log("ABCD" + data);
  });
}
```

See also [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)

**Hint** `map`, `do`, `toPromise`, ... need to be imported to become available.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

or just

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues with Promises myself in Ionic2/Angular2. You could try to replace the Promise with an Observable instead in your service:

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:9999/KY Mobile/Promo/selectPromo.php').map(res =>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
        observer.next(data)
        observer.complete();
    });
 });
```

Then, in the home page.

```
loadPromo(){
  this.promoService.load().subscribe(data=>{
     this.promos = data;
     console.log("ABCD" + data);
  });
}
```