# Angular 11 dynamically assign [icon] attribute for fa-icon

Tags: angular

Hi Im trying to do this in an html template in angular. It shows the icon I want, but the function gets called like much to often... what am I missing here?
Template

```html
<li class="pet-list__entry" *ngFor="let pet of listOfPets">
    <div class="pet-list__entry__image-segment">
      <fa-icon [icon]=getIcon(pet.type)></fa-icon>
    </div>
    <div  class="pet-list__entry__data-segment">
      {{ pet.name }}
    </div>
  </li>
```

```js
getIcon(id: string): string {
    const  iconName = this[id];
    console.log(iconName);
    return iconName;
  }
```

Console output: (why?)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The `getIcon()` function is being called so many times because of the way Angular works. The property bindings `[]` are evaluated at every change detection cycle.

See [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639817/angular-2-property-binding-lifecycle) to get a full explanation.

But you can optimize it binding to a property instead a function, which is the recommended way of binding properties.

For example, in your case, if you know what are the possible icon classes, you can do something like:

```
// component.ts
const icons = {
    1: 'dog',
    2: 'cat'
}
```

```
<!-- component.html -->
...
<fa-icon [icon]="icons[pet.type]"></fa-icon>
...
```