# How to cache and share Http get() response?

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular2-http

Following this course https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angular-2-getting-started and github materials [product.service](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/blob/master/APM%20-%20Final/app/products/product.service.ts) in that course trying to 
avoid calling http.get() request every time I click the link.
I think it is a big waste to load file every time instead of saving it as an object in memory.

Trying to replace this code:

```
    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

with this one:

```
    public _observable: Observable<IProduct[]>;

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    console.log('_observable before: ' + (this._observable));
    if(this._observable===undefined){
        console.log('_observable inside 1: ' + (this._observable));
        this._observable=this._http.get(this._productUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All inside observable: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
        console.log('_observable inside 2: ' + (this._observable));
    }

    console.log('_observable after: ' + (this._observable));
    return this._observable;
}
```

this line should never be called if `this._observable` is underfined   `this._observable=this._http.get(this._productUrl)`

BUT IT IS CALLED!!!!

In a chrome console:

```
_observable before: [object Object]
product.service.ts:25 _observable after: [object Object]
product.service.ts:20 All inside observable:...
```

Last line shouldn't appear!

Comment: Is the ProductListComponent subscribing to the observable again? If so, it will execute it again.

Comment: Check out the solutions presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Comment: actually, you guided me to the right direction
it is about caching and adding magic words publishReplay(1) and refCount
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0
if you do post the answer i will mark it as an answer

Comment: @DeborahK Thank you for the great course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid file being loaded you need to include to lines of code inside if statements:

```
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount()
```

The full code goes here:

```
    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    console.log('_observable before: ' + (this._observable));
    if(this._observable===undefined){
        console.log('_observable inside 1: ' + (this._observable));
        this._observable=this._http.get(this._productUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount()
            .do(data => console.log('All inside observable: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
        console.log('_observable inside 2: ' + (this._observable));
    }

    console.log('_observable after: ' + (this._observable));
    return this._observable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

_observable before is an object in log. And "last line" comment is outside if-else. Why not try :

```
    if (!Object.keys(this._observable).length) {
   console.log('_observable inside 1: ' + (this._observable));
    this._observable=this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All inside observable: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
        console.log('_observable inside 2: ' + (this._observable));
        return this._observable;
   } else {
        console.log('_observable after: ' + (this._observable));
        return this._observable;
   }
```

Comment: results are the same

Answer (score 1):

For your code

```
 getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
    .publishReplay(1)
     .refCount()
    .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now you dont need to think about  those conditions. publishReplay, refCount will share the same state among all observers. So publishReplay will help you to cache data and refCount will help observer to be available.

Comment: I was hoping that @DeborahK will post this already finished answer but you were the first

Comment: Without if statements it does no affect