# Store HTML page in memory with Angular2

Tags: html, memory, typescript, angular

I would like to keep web page in memory so that when I click on back button (not the one on web browser) or on a routerlink, the HTML page instantly loads if I already visit it(because I have some data to load that I don't want to be reload).

I've seen a method with tabbed interface :  https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target.en.html#tab1
but it is not adapted for my code architecture.

I'm using `routerlink`in angular2 to navigate threw pages and a back button calling a function on click to go to the previous page.

I try to detail as far as I can so people can understand better my code architecture and the way `routerlink` method works.

Back button function (works independently from `routerlink`) :

```
 goBack() {
 window.history.back();
 }
```

The router link method from page 1 to page 2:

page1.html :

```
<a[routerLink]="['PAGE2']"> go to page 2</a>
```

page1.ts component:

```
 import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
 @Component({
 selector: 'page1',
 templateUrl: 'page1.html',
 styleUrls:  ['page1.css'],
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
 })
```

main.ts :

```
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/page2',  name: 'PAGE2',  component: Page2}]) //component representing class Page2 in page2.ts
```

Any idea to help me manage it is welcomed, thanks by advance !

Answer (score 2):

Just cache the data in the service like explained in [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)

There is currently no way to prevent the router from re-creating the component when you route away and back to the component.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for those having the same problem, I think the best way to manage it is to map the data into a `localStorage key` like this :

```
  localStorage.setItem('favoris',JSON.stringify(my_array)); //set my data array
  array =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name')); //get in array
```

And then `ngOnInit`in the class called by the router will call the initial function depending of `localStorage key` being true or not.