# (Ionic/ Angular 2) Calling service in NgFor?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this `ngFor`:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let review of reviews">
    <ion-card-content>
        {{getUserName(review.user_ID)}}
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I need to show the user name, but to get user name I need to call user service to get the username. The problem is when I try this. The page keeps loading and loading. What is the correct way to call service inside `ngFor`?

This is my getUserName method:

```
 getUserName(userId) {
     this.userService.loadUserById(userId)
        .then(dataUser => {
          this.user = dataUser;
        });

     return this.user; 
 }
```

And when I get the object how to access the object property like in HTML? (Example: user.firstName). Thanks.

Comment: How does your `loadUserById` method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would at least need some cache to not call out to the server for every change detection cycle, which is when `getUsername(review.uer_ID)` is called like for example explained in [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)

A better way would be to fetch all usernames for all `reviews` in advance and make them available as array you bind to inside `*ngFor`.

Calling methods that are expensive or have side effects from templates is strongly discouraged because it is extremly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks , i have change my backend code so i can retrieve data only from reviews.