# Angular2: Example with multiple http calls (typeahead) with observables

Tags: caching, angular, angular2-http, angular2-observables

So I am working on couple of cases in my app where I need the following to happen

When event triggered, do the following

- List item
- check if the data with that context is already cached, serve cached
- if no cache, debounce 500ms
- check if other http calls are running (for the same context) and kill them
- make http call
- On success cache and update/replace model data

Pretty much standard when it comes to typeahead functionality

I would like to use observables with this... in the way, I can cancel them if previous calls are running

any good tutorials on that? I was looking around, couldn't find anything remotely up to date

OK, to give you some clue what I did now:

```
onChartSelection(chart: any){

        let date1:any, date2:any;

        try{
            date1 = Math.round(chart.xAxis[0].min);
            date2 = Math.round(chart.xAxis[0].max);

            let data = this.tableService.getCachedChartData(this.currentTable, date1, date2);

            if(data){
                this.table.data = data;
            }else{

                if(this.chartTableRes){
                    this.chartTableRes.unsubscribe();
                }

                this.chartTableRes = this.tableService.getChartTable(this.currentTable, date1, date2)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.table.data = data;
                        this.chartTableRes = null;
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
            }

        }catch(e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Missing debounce here

-- I ended up implementing lodash's debounce

```
import {debounce} from 'lodash';
...

onChartSelectionDebaunced: Function;

constructor(...){
    ...
    this.onChartSelectionDebaunced = debounce(this.onChartSelection, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debaunce you can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce). The function will look this way:

```
onChartSelection: Function = _.debounce((chart: any) => {
   ...
});
```

Regarding the cancelation of Observable, it is better to use Observable method [share](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/share.html). In your case you should change the method `getChartTable` in your `tableService` by adding `.share()` to your Observable that you return.

This way there will be only one call done to the server even if you subscribe to it multiple times (without this every new subscription will invoke new call).

Take a look at: [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)

Comment: cheers for the suggestions... I am trying not to add underscore to the project... the js assets are already big as is :P... would be nice to have a angular2 version of this :) will check out the share method ;)

Comment: So you should try to use debounder from RxJS that you already have in your project: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/debounce.md

Comment: Looking at the code but doesn't make sense to me in http context... will figure it out, thanks

Comment: ended up using lodash's debounce... part of the implementation included in the question. Thanks @Baumi