# How do you use @Input with components created with a ComponentFactoryResolver?

Tags: angular

Is there a method that can be used to define an @Input property on an Angular 2 component that's created dynamically?

I'm using the [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentFactoryResolver-class.html) to create components in a container component.  For example:

```
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentName);

let componentRef = entryPoint.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Where "entryPoint" is something like this in the component HTML:

```
<div #entryPoint></div>
```

And defined in my container component with:

```
@ViewChild('entryPoint', { read: ViewContainerRef } entryPoint: ViewContainerRef;
```

This works well, but I can't find a way to make an @Input property work on the newly created component.  I know that you can explicitly set public properties on the component class, but this doesn't seem to work with ng-reflect.  Prior to making this change I had a "selected" property decorated with "@Input()" that caused Angular to add the following to the DOM:

```
<my-component ng-reflected-selected="true"></my-component>
```

With this in place I was able to dynamically update the markup to switch a CSS class:

```
<div class="header" [class.active-header]="selected === true"></div>
```

Based on some searching I was able to find a method to make "@Output" work as expected, but I've yet to find anything for @Input.

Let me know if additional context would be helpful and I'd be happy to add it.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

No, Angular2 bindings only work with components and directives statically added to the template of a component.

For all other situations use shared services like explained in https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

You can also use

```
let componentRef = entryPoint.createComponent(componentFactory);
componentRef.instance.someProp = 'someValue';
componentRef.instance.someObservableOrEventEmitter.subscribe(data => this.prop = data);
```

Comment: How would you change the .style property of the component's resulting DOM element? ie this.cmpRef._hostElement.nativeElement.style... without using the private variable

Comment: You can add `@HostBinding('style.border') borderStyle:string;` to the component and then set it like `componentRef.instance.borderStyle = 'solid 3px red';` Not sure if this is what you want. Otherwise there aren't many options to set styles dynamically.

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren did you downvote? Was this accidentally?

Comment: I did not intentially downvote. Apologies for this - I think I was just able to amend this accident by upvoting back to zero. But I see a stackoverflow ui bug that won't allow me to now upvote so that it becomes 1

Comment: thank you for your help. If instead, I just passed an object property to the child (that contains key/prop for each style I want to change), what syntax would I use in the child to change its resulting dom element?

Comment: I don't know a way to style the child element itself this way. You could add `[ngStyle]="someStyle"` to a child element of the dynamically added element and style this by setting `someStyle` to the object you mentioned. You could now try to upvote again. I might work now.

Comment: No worries. I was just wondering if someone thinks there is something wrong with my answer.

Comment: never me - I am extremely grateful for the help you have shared with me

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm interested in using the imperative approach you've outlined here but whenever I try it I get type errors that the EventEmitter property does not exist on type {}. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The component needs to have an `someObservableOrEventEmitter:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter()`. If this doesn't help, please create a new question with the code you are using and eventually a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer All of the components that I've included in entryComponents contain the EventEmitter property. I think that the problem I'm struggling with is how how the type system actually knows what the type of ComponentRef will ultimately be to be aware of the Emitter

Comment: I managed to get it to work by casting the ComponetRef to "any":

let componentRef = this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(factory);
    let dynamicRef = componentRef as any;

    dynamicRef.instance.change.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

Not sure if this is a good idea though because it breaks type safety for the dynamically created components

Comment: I think `CompinentRef<MyComponent>` should work as well

Comment: When I do this, componentRef.instance.someProp = 'someValue'; doesn't trigger ngOnChanges on the child component. Are there more steps that need to be done for this tow work?

Comment: I posted a comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681

Comment: @Jus10 You can see my answer if you're still curious... five years later.

Answer (score 22):

Since **14.1.0**, Angular added the **setInput()** method to directly set or update @Input to the component reference.

```js
this.componentRef.setInput('someInput', this.value);
```

> Using this method will properly mark for check component using the OnPush change detection strategy. It will also assure that the OnChanges lifecycle hook runs when a dynamically created component is change-detected.

If the value will change, I use this approach:

```js
@Input()
public value: string;    

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.component);
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.value) {
        this.componentRef?.setInput('someInput', this.value); // Updated with every change from the parent component.
    }
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.componentRef?.destroy(); // Don't forget to destroy the component.
}
```

[API](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#setinput)

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER FOR >14

Comment: Full article: https://netbasal.com/a-new-way-to-set-inputs-on-angular-componentrefs-6214f95db63d

Comment: @Simon_Weaver thanks for pointing to the article! This is what I've been looking for

Answer (score 2):

[The Günter Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39280103/11347983) is correct. But if you, like I was, have troubles with rendering `@Input` data in the component template, you should try this:

1. Run your component creating code in `ngAfterViewInit`.
2. Add `componentRef.instance.ngOnInit()` as a last line.
3. Inside `ngOnInit` of your dynamically created component run `detectChanges` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef`.