# Angular: passing data back from dynamic component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Based on an [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) in the cookbook, I am creating components dynamically like this:

```
    private loadComponent(): void {
        const componentFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyInputComponent);

        const viewContainerRef = this.componentHost.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();

        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (<IComponent>componentRef.instance).data = data;
}
```

MyInputComponent's template would look like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.inputProp">
```

I need to update the value of data.inputProp in the parent when the user types in the input.

I have seen this in some examples, but not sure what it does?

```
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

I've also read about [subscribing to a child's EventEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280057/how-do-you-use-input-with-components-created-with-a-componentfactoryresolver) in the parent, but only seen examples of that using click events. What is the better approach for updating all kinds of data including text inputs back to the parent?

I am using Angular 4 RC3

Comment: Are you loading components dynamically or is it a pre-created component?

Comment: Thanks for your time Gary, the instances of the components are craeted and loaded dynamically

Comment: detectChanges() will trigger manual change detection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send data to dynamically created component.

```
this.componentRef.instance.variableName = 'abc';  // here variableName is a variable of dynamic component.
```

If you want to get data from dynamically created component.

```
this.componentRef.instance.observeVariable.subscribe(result => { this.v = result;  // here observeVariable is an Observable in dynamic component(ie. this.componentRef).
```

Comment: cool. does that mean you are asking the observeVariabel to be created as an observable? I was tying this out with events through services and seems like you cannot inject a service to a dynamic component. It gives zone error. How do you suggest create an observable for the variable here. observable.create or behavioursubject?

Comment: observeVariable: Subject<any> = new Subject(); will do the trick

Comment: Ok let me try this. Is this supposed to be in the service or from the dynamic component?

Comment: it will be from dynamic component.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I hook up that subject in the dynamic component to a text input which next's each key change? I miss ng-include and bindings...

Comment: juat get the input's value in a variable and ngOnChange function pass that varibale in subject.next() and you'll get the value.