# How to achieve two way data binding in case of dynamic loading of child component using ComponentFactoryResolver

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular6, kendo-ui-angular2

I am adding child component dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver and able to using ngModel in the child component but it's working as a one way data binding rather than two way.

I tried by adding child component tag and it's working but in my case I can't add that. So need a solution with ComponentFactoryResolver. Please check the below stackblitz for better understanding. i need the parent component vlue to be update on second text box value change.

[Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pa5hcc?file=app/app.component.ts).

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AppChildComponent);
const component = factory.create(this.ViewContainerRef.parentInjector);
component.instance['childData']=this.parentData;
this.ViewContainerRef.insert(component.hostView);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848369/angular-passing-data-back-from-dynamic-component

Comment: You need to convert the dynamically created component variable as an observable. Then you can listen for the changes in the main component

Comment: I suggest you use an object, not a string, so. When pass data, pass the reference and change in child,change the property, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umds2q?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts