# Angular 2 show mixed elements array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

What I want to accomplish is to show all elements from an array. This array contains various types of components (yes, components), and all these components extends from an abstract class.

**Here's my code:**

Abstract Class Plugin:

```
export abstract class Plugin {
constructor() { }
}
```

Watch Component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'watch',
template: `
    {{clock | async | date:'medium'}} 
 `
})

export class WatchCmpt extends Plugin {
    clock = Observable.interval(1000).map(() => new Date())
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
}
```

Demo Component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'demo',
template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
`
})

export class DemoCmpt extends Plugin {
     name: string = "Jose";
     constructor() {
        super();
     }
}
```

I'm using this code in my view to display it in my html file:

```
<? *ngFor="let target of targetList; let x = index">{{target}} </?>
```

What should I use in the  `<?>` ?

`targetList` is an array like this:
`[demo, watch]`

**EDIT:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dndPanel',
    templateUrl: 'dragNdropPanel.cmpt.html'
 })

export class DragNDropPanelCmpt {
   @ViewChild(DemoCmpt) demo1: DemoCmpt;
   @ViewChild(WatchCmpt) watch: WatchCmpt;

   constructor() {
   }

   targetList: Plugin[] = [
      this.demo1,
      this.watch,
   ];

   addTo($event: any) {
      this.targetList.push($event.dragData);
  }
}
```

This is the complete HTML:

```
   div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-info" dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="targetList">
        <div class="panel-heading">Target List</div>
        <div class="panel-body" dnd-droppable (onDropSuccess)="addTo($event)" [dropZones]="['source-dropZone']">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li *ngFor="let target of targetList; let x = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="x" [dragEnabled]="true">
                    {{target}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `targetList` declared?

Comment: @Aravind i edited the question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could achieve what I needed using **ComponentFactory**. I found an interesting article in [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-aot-dynamic-components/) website, it does exactly what I wanted: Render many different components in a single view from a list without hardcoding with ngSwitch or other more complex(to me) tasks.

I appreciate all the answers and comments

Comment: Great find. Didn't realize that. Are you able to configure the component (passing \@input values and receiving \@output events)?

Comment: @JoelJeske now I'm trying to make that work, if i can do it, or if i find something i'll let you know

Comment: @JoelJeske I made it... you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39280103/2979805) it worked perfectly to me

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are trying to use concrete elements inside of your generic list. A generic list can only operate on its elements as of the API defined by the parent abstract class.

In other words, you can only assume the list contains objects of type `Plugin`. Type plugin is not a component so you cannot assume children are components. Angular does not have a great way to extend components, so your idea of making OO components does not work out.

Example:

What if I created another class that extends `Plugin`, but is not a `@Component`? How would the list render a non-component?

Comment: That is correct and i understand that, right now i want to render the components, is there something that i can use to do that?

Comment: Well your example is a fixed set of components. If that is really the case, I would simply hard-code the components you want to render right in the template.

Comment: At the time it is, but i want to create a dashboard with drag and drop components, so i need to put any kind of components inside the array and render them

Comment: That makes sense. I would look at either one of these guides:
[Dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) or the much simpler [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). The switch would allow you to detect the component type and render the component desired in the template

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the `<?>` the router outlet.

Router outlet is used to rote the componet output to the main container.

You use the outlet as the tag added to the template superclass.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If you ever read about a [Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) it will tell you that

> The Angular Router enables navigation from one view to the next as users perform application tasks.

The problem with the design components are object oriented and doesn't have a common override interface. Thus the coding performs a bit harder especially bumping one component over another with the card layout.