# Dynamic Component Loading in Angular with Inputs

Tags: angular

I know that in order to create a component dynamically you can do something like this

```
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

let viewContainerRef = this.host.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();

let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
componentref.instance.data = someData;
```

`ngOnInit` is called right after `viewContainerRef.createComponent()`, which is before the data property is patched through to the component. In my `ngOnInit` I have logic that needs all properties in advance. How can I pass my props to the component before it is created?

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39280103/5043867

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because that post addresses passing properties, but does not address passing them before ``ngOnInit`` as would be the case with a statically added component (and is what I'm interested in).

Comment: Just a suggestion, might help you anyhow :)

Comment: you want to check the input property before ngOnInit?

Comment: Yes like I pass a bunch of data to this component, and in ``ngOnInit`` I want to map it in some way and use it in various parts of the component.

Comment: For example, if I was using router outlets for the components I would check query params in ``ngOnInit``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 classes brings a new syntax for setters on object properties.

> The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called
>   when there is an attempt to set that property.

**Try this**

```
import { Component, Input , OnInit} from '@angular/core';    
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{_name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  _name: string;
  @Input() set name(value) {
    //do your logic here
    this._name = value;
    console.log(value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-com-set

Comment: This is very useful and interesting. But my template is going to have tons of nulls to deal with after creation, which is a huge hassle. The nice thing about routing to a component is I have all of the params I need at component creation time. Is there a way to sort of mimic this routing with components with dynamic component creation? For example, I use the data that is passed in to make a service call. Of course your answer covers this, but I wonder if there are alternatives.

Comment: Sorry could not think of any other approach!

Comment: What about using providers?

Comment: ya great idea Try that!