# Subscribing on an rxjs Observer multiple times without executing multiple requests

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, angular, rxjs, observable

So I am trying to implement a custom XHRBackend for my Angular 2 app. This is my class:

```
import {Request, XHRBackend, BrowserXhr, ResponseOptions, XSRFStrategy} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/observable/throw";
import {SlimLoadingBarService} from "ng2-slim-loading-bar";

export class LoadingBarXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {
    constructor(_browserXhr: BrowserXhr, _baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions, _xsrfStrategy: XSRFStrategy, private slimLoadingBarService: SlimLoadingBarService) {
        super(_browserXhr, _baseResponseOptions, _xsrfStrategy);
    }

    createConnection(request: Request) {
        this.slimLoadingBarService.start();

        let xhrConnection = super.createConnection(request);

        xhrConnection.response.share().subscribe(() => {
            this.slimLoadingBarService.complete();
        });

        return xhrConnection;
    }

}
```

As you can see I tried using the .share() method as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-angular-2-apps-using-observable-data-1#pitfall2avoidduplicatehttpcalls), but it does not work the way I expect it to.

I want to "hook in" to the creation and completion of an XHR request to display a loading bar. But if I leave that .share() call out I get a separate HTTP request for each .subscribe() call I make.

But if I use .share() my second Subscription won't be executed at all :(

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
createConnection(request: Request) {
    this.slimLoadingBarService.start();

    let xhrConnection = super.createConnection(request).response.share();

    xhrConnection.subscribe(() => {
        this.slimLoadingBarService.complete();
    });

    return xhrConnection;
}
```

You need to `share()` before subscribing and returning, so that both the internal and the external one gets the multicasted version of the observable.

Note however that share turns the obseravble in to a hot observable, so you might want to do this instead:

```
createConnection(request: Request) {
    return Observable.defer(() => {
        this.slimLoadingBarService.start();

        return super.createConnection(request).response
            .do(() => this.slimLoadingBarService.complete());
    });
}
```

`Observable.defer` means that none of the code inside of it will be executed untill you actually subscribe to it. The `do` operator taps in to the event stream without affecting the stream.