# In Angular2 how do you detect that a filter/pipes returned no results

Tags: angular

I want to show a message when the filter returns an empty array e.g. "No results found"

**This is my ngFor list that has a filter**

```
 <li class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let item of jobs | jobsFilter: [originalJobList, region, county, type]"></li>

<p>No results found</p>
```

Its easy if theres no filter, but because theres a filter i dont no how to say filter returned no results.

**This is my filter:**

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'jobsFilter',
  pure: true
})

export class JobsFilter {
   transform(items: any, [originalList, region, county, type]: any) {
      //Filter options:
        var overallResults = originalList;
        var filterByRegion = false;
        var filterByCounty = false;
        var filterByType = false;

        if (region !== "Filter by Region") filterByRegion = true;

        if (county !== "Filter by County") filterByCounty = true;

        if (type !== "Filter by Type") filterByType = true;

        if (filterByType) overallResults = overallResults.filter(item => item.type === type);

        if (filterByRegion) overallResults = overallResults.filter(item => item.region === region);

        if (filterByCounty) overallResults = overallResults.filter(item => item.county === county);

        return overallResults;
  }
}
```

> This all works but I just need to show the users that there filter
>   return no results with a message rather than empty screen.

Comment: You can inject component in your pipe and change component property if pipe returns 0 items. Or maybe inject service. Here's an idea https://plnkr.co/edit/xJfmBs7djfibyrjl7NHN?p=preview

Comment: Or you can pass mutable property in your pipe https://plnkr.co/edit/temmLoKnCpiA8BtCwFlE?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let item of jobs | jobsFilter: [originalJobList, region, county, type]"></li>

<p *ngIf="!(jobs | jobsFilter: [originalJobList, region, county, type]?.length)">No results found</p>
```

Comment: But that shows that this filter-based approach is wrong. Angular chose not to add a filter pipe, on purpose, because they think it's a costly operation that shouldn't be done in the view, every time change detection is applied, but in the component, when needed. That's, IMHO, the best solution: filter in the component, and expose the filtered array to the view.

Comment: The example didnt work. I got this error: "caused by: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Comment: That's another approach and probably a good idea. I'd say id depends on how expensive the pipe operation is. Readability will also become better in this concrete case. For several things Angular2 does reuse the expression. For example if `(observable | async)` is used twice in the view Angular will subscribe only once.

Comment: @AngularM that sounds like a bug in your filter. You need to ensure the filter doesn't throw when `jobs` is `null`.

Comment: `transform(...) { if(!originalList) return; ...`

Comment: I no longer get the console error and the filter works. But your code doesnt do anything for : "<p *ngIf="jobs | jobsFilter: [originalJobList, region, county, type]?.length">No results found</p>"

Comment: Another solution? if I filter my observable, I assume I should get the instance of the updated observable. Replicating the filter pipe does not make much sense IMO.

Comment: @DAT Not sure I understand your comment. The `as` supported by `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` might be useful or perhaps adding `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` (like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756526/217408) on your observable might help solving your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Read the following post:

https://netbasal.com/using-pipe-results-in-angular-templates-430683fa2213

Snippet:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf=”(items | filter:search.value) as result”>

  <div *ngFor=”let item of result”>
    {{item}}
  </div>

  <p>Count: <b>{{result.length}}</b></p>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: This Answer does not tackle the question head on

Comment: It does answer. Just adjust the code above to have another `*ngIf="!result.lenght"`