# Angular 2, data from HTTP service loaded just once and shared between more components of a router

Tags: http, angular, observablecollection, angular2-routing, angular2-services

This is my plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/SzaI1ffiCxFk7BE3Ke8o?p=preview

As you can see, my app gets data from an HTTP service. These data are shared between the components of an angular router.

The question is, I definitely don't want every component to load data from the http service everytime it is initialized (inside `OnNgInit` method).
My app should instead load data from http service just at the beginning (and that's why I put the service `PlanService.loadData()` inside `OnNgInit` method of `AppComponent`), and save them inside a local instance of the Object Plan. Then every component should get those data (in their initialization phase) from a service `PlanService.getData()`.
I tried to do this, but without success.
Is there a different approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. The Plunker example seems not working ;( ...

Comment: Thanks for the note. I'll have a look when I have more time. Probably just the boilerplate code (NgModule, ...). I'm pretty sure the core of the solution can be used unchanged.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried but it seems to call the http service everytime the component is initialized... it seems not storing data. 
Here my updated plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/SzaI1ffiCxFk7BE3Ke8o?p=preview

Comment: Did you provide the service on the component? In this case a new service instance will be created for each component. If you provide it in `@NgModule()` only a single instance of the service will be created.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ok, perfect, thanks a lot! I deleted the service inside the providers of the components and now it works, but... not like I'd want to. I'll explain better. When I modify data inside component form, I don't want the change to affect the other components, the change would affect data only inside the component until user click on "UPDATE" button. Is there a way to prevent this "binding"?
Here is [my plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/SzaI1ffiCxFk7BE3Ke8o?p=preview)

Comment: Not directly. You would need to assign a copy of the object (I found the `Plan` class in your Plunker for example) to a property and bind to this property instead. Then on "UPDATE" you go through the properties and update the orginal instance. I don't know a better way.

Comment: Oh, I tried but without success... where should I have to assign it? I'm not so sure about the better way to do it...

Comment: Instead of `this.plan = plan;` use `this.plan = Object.assign({}, plan);`

Comment: Ooooh thanks a lot @GünterZöchbauer, you finally solved my issue. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)