# Resolve id in pipe with a service

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I will resolve an ID with a pipe.

I think it isn't the best way to call the service/api every time?

Is it better to store all countries before? How could I return the country name within pipe?

service:

```
getCountry(id:number) {
   return this._http.get(this.apiUrl + "/country/" + id).map(res => res.json());
}
```

pipe:

```
export class ResolvePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public _formDataService: FormDataService) {}
  transform(value: number, args: any[]): any {
    this._formDataService.getCountry(value).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data[0].name)
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
<tr (click)="showProfile(customer)" *ngFor="let customer of (customers | search:term)">
   <td>...</td><td>{{customer.country_id | resolve | async}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to return an `Observable`. When you call `subscribe()` a `Subscription` will be returned. Also you need to actually return something from `transform()` hence the added `return`

```ts
export class ResolvePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public _formDataService: FormDataService) {}
  transform(value: number, args: any[]): any {
    // added `return` and changed `subscribe` to `map`
    return this._formDataService.getCountry(value).map(
      data => {
        console.log(data[0].name);
        return data; // with `{ }` explicit `return` is required
      });
    )
  }
}
```

then you can use the pipe like

```ts
<div>{{someId | myIdPipe | async}}</div>
```

or

```ts
<some-comp [idProp]="someId | myIdPipe | async></some-comp>
```

The `async` pipe subscribes to the `Observable` returned from `transform` and uses the resulting value for the binding.

Comment: thank you, works, but it's very slow. What can I do to speed up the performance?

Comment: Hard to tell from here what is slow. Does the response from the server take such a long time? Is the pipe executed so often that it slows down you application. I can't tell from here. You might maintain a cache within `FormDataService` like discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Comment: Yes, it's called some 1000 times. A cache should solve this problem.

Comment: Would be insteresting why it's called that often. Do you use it on so many bindings or is the `value` changing so often? Angular doesn't by itself call a pipe more than once. Perhaps you have set `pure: false` which makes Angular to execute the pipe every time change detection runs - which is quite often.

Comment: I have updated my post. I use the filter in a for loop.

Comment: and there are 1000 customers or is `term` changing a lot? In this case I'd strongly suggest a cache. Perhaps you can do something that not a request per id is made but only one request for all ids. This would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: and how you would handle the single request? cache the result in pipe?

Comment: I would cache the results in the `FormDataService` because this way every pipe instance can benefit from the cache, otherwise each pipe has its own cache and when `*ngFor` recreates the rows when `term` changes, all pipes are destroyed and recreated and the cache won't have any effect.