# Angular2 observable share is not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services, rxjs5

Angular2 Observable share is not working and duplicate http calls going

**BuildingService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class BuildingService {

constructor(private http: Http){       
  }

buildings$: Observable<Building[]>;
this.buildings: Building[];

getData() : Observable<Building[]>{
     this.buildings$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/buildings').share().map(this.extractData);
     this.buildings$.subscribe(buildings => this.buildings = buildings);
     return this.buildings$;
  }

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
} 

}
```

**component1.ts**

```
export class component1 {
constructor( private  buildingService: BuildingService) {}

this.subscription = this.buildingService.getData()
            .subscribe(buildings => console.log(buildings),
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

**component2.ts**

```
export class component2 {
constructor( private  buildingService: BuildingService) {}

this.subscription = this.buildingService.getData()
            .subscribe(buildings => console.log(buildings),
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

share is not working, multiple http calls are going. Even I tried code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36291681/2742156)

but no use.

Can somebody please let me know how to avoid duplicate http calls with Angular Observable?

Comment: have you tried `publish().refCount()` instead of `share()`

Comment: @SurajRao That's just an alias to `share()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/26490/caching-http-responses#t=201701031007534099407

Comment: thanks @martin I was looking at the second answer in OPs [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36296015/4826457)

Comment: `publishLast().refCount()`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this is just misunderstanding of what `share()` does.

When you call `this.buildings$.subscribe(...)` it makes a `ConnectableObservable` thanks to `share()` operator which is immediately followed by `connect()`.

If you make another subscription while the HTTP request is pending it will just add another Observer to the `ConnectableObservable` and when the response is ready it'll be sent to both Observers. However if you let `this.buildings$` to complete and after that you subscribe again it'll make another HTTP request because the `ConnectableObservable` is not connected to its source.

What you want instead is `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` (or `shareReplay(1)` since RxJS 5.4.0) that replays the last item emitted from the source. Very likely you'll also want to append `take(1)` to properly complete the chain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. publishReplay(1).refCount() will not even allow http call when I do getData() for the second time. Since I'm doing filtering on the returned data, I need to have exact one backend call when I do getData() all the time.
Could you please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: @PratapA.K Can you make pnlkr or jsbin reproducing your problem?

Comment: creating pnlkr is quite difficult for me since I have multiple components and separate filter module.
I have created a new question for my one more doubt. Could you please take a look?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458117/angular2-avoid-updating-reference-variable-also

Comment: @martin now you could use .shareReplay(1) which is an alias of .publishReplay(1).refCount()

Comment: @JakubBarczyk True

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new stream with every `.getData()`-call here:

```
this.buildings$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/buildings').share().map(this.extractData);
```

If you want to "share" data between components and prevent multiple rest-calls, you would have to most likely use the replay-feature of rxjs, you could for example do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class BuildingService {

constructor(private http: Http){}

buildings$: Observable<Building[]>;
this.buildings: Building[];

getData(fetchNew: boolean = false) : Observable<Building[]>{
     if (fetchNew || !this.buildings$) {
         this.buildings$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/buildings')
             .map(this.extractData)
             .publishReplay(1)
             .refCount();
         this.buildings$.subscribe(buildings => this.buildings = buildings);
     }
     return this.buildings$;
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
  }
}
```

`publishReplay(1)` will re-emit("replay") the last emitted data to future subscribers, so no new call will be made.

Comment: how to have exact one backend call when I do getData(). I need to make backend call each time I call getData() method.

Comment: I understood your question that you do __not__ want to have multiple rest-calls to be made with every `getData()` ... you cannot call a function twice and say "but i just want to do that part once" - you could define how long the data should be kept (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/26490/caching-http-responses#t=201701031007534099407) - but I think for a _proper_ solution you should split up the logic of data-fetching and storing the data that will give you more flixibility - maybe you want to have a look at ngrx: https://github.com/ngrx/store

Answer (score -3):

You're subscribing to the observable in both the service and the components. Try this as the getData method in your service:

```
getData() : Observable<Building[]>{
 return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/buildings')
    .map(this.extractData);
}
```

Comment: He is using share(). That will not really matter

Comment: This will cause a new rest-call with every `getData().subscribe()`