# angular2 avoid updating reference variable also

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs5

why angular2 is updating all the references of a variable?

**Problem Statement:**
I have a service which returns observable on calling getData method

```
@Injectable()
export class BuildingService {

constructor(private http: Http){       
  }

buildings$: Observable<Building[]>;

getData() : Observable<Building[]>{
     if (this.buildings$) {
        this.buildings$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/buildings')
         .map(this.extractData)
         .publishReplay(1)
         .refCount();     
     }
     return this.buildings$;
  }

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
} 
}
```

in component I'm subscribing to observable returned from getData method and doing some filtering and it is working fine

```
export class Component1 implements onInit{

   constructor(private _buildingService: BuildingService) {}

   buildings: Building[] = [];

   ngOnInit() {
        this._buildingService.getData()
        .subscribe(buildings => {
            this.buildings = buildings;
            this.buildings.forEach((building, index){
                if (building.id === 0) {
                    this.buildings.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        });     
   }

getUnfilteredData() {
    this._buildingService.getData()
        .subscribe(buildings => {
            this.buildings = buildings;         
        });
   }
}
```

but even when I call getUnfilteredData() also, I am getting previously filtered data. Can somebody please explain why is this behaviour and how to avoid this?

Comment: You first call `ngOnInit`, then filter `this.buildings`. Later on you call the same service and inside the callback `buildings` is `this.buildings`? Can you `console.log(buildings);` inside the subscribes?

Comment: @echonax I did console.log(buildings) inside getUnfilteredData. I am getting filtered data instead of unfiltered data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.publishReplay(1).refCount();` to cache the data for multiple subscribers which is working. But in your `ngOninit` you are taking the original data reference into `this.buildings` and splicing it. So your cached data is also affected.

Solution is to slice(make a copy) the array into `this.buildings` before filtering.

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this._buildingService.getData()
        .subscribe(buildings => {
            this.buildings = buildings.slice();//slice instead of taking reference
            this.buildings.forEach((building, index){
                if (building.id === 0) {
                    this.buildings.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        });     
   }
```

Or you could do this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
            this.buildings = [];
            this._buildingService.getData()
            .subscribe(buildings => {

                buildings.forEach((building){
                    if (building.id !== 0) {
                        this.buildings.push(building);
                    }
                });
            });     
       }
```

Comment: What If buildings array contains one more array inside? Looks like slice is not working with array inside an array.

Comment: How would you reset the cache for this?

Comment: @Tudor-RaduBarbu hmm.. you can set `buildings$` to null... check http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0