# share() not working in Angular HTTP calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I just noticed that my HTTP calls were not shared anymore between components.
I am not sure since which version.

Already checked this solution:
[Angular2 observable share is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440923/angular2-observable-share-is-not-working)

which makes the problem even worse (more HTTP calls), I must confess I always had a hard time understanding rxjs.

Here is my service function:

```
getSomeData(): Promise < any > 
{
    if(this.data) // should keep service from doing extra http for the same request
    {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.http.post(this.createURL('getData',{}),JSON.stringify({}), this.createGetOptions())
            .timeout(environment.timeout)
            .share()
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response;
            }).toPromise();
    }
}
```

I call it from different components

```
this.service.getSomeData().then((data: any) => 
{
    if (data) {
   ...
```

`createGetOptions` just adds headers like `'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'`

Comment: Are you providing the service at component level or module level or root level? Also does all the components fall in same module?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`pipe`** operator in Angular 6+ as follows instead of chaining:

**Example -**

```
getSomeData(): Promise < any > 
{
    if(this.data) // should keep service from doing extra http for the same request
    {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    else
    {
     return this.http.post(this.createURL('getData',{}),JSON.stringify({}), this.createGetOptions()).pipe(
                timeout(environment.timeout),
                share(),
                map((response: Response) => {
                    return response;
                })).toPromise();
    }
}
```

Also make sure you import share as follows:

```
import {share} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question, I was just commenting on my way :)

Comment: it does not work :-(, same as before, the service does the http request more than once

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my library ngx-RxCache. I wrote it exactly for this kind of thing.

https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: why would one need a library while it's a typical use case for rxjs and it was supported bu previous versions of angular ?

Comment: I wrote an article on the library here if you want an answer to that question https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb