# Angular 2 HTTP . Store response in array

Tags: http, angular

So I have this Service in Angular2

```
fetchData(){
    return this.http.get('https://ng-workout.firebaseio.com/Workouts/.json').map(
        (res) => res.json()
    );
}
```

And then this Component

```
export class HomeComponent  {

workouts = [];

constructor(private dataService: DataService){
}

ngOnInit(){
this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
    data=> this.workouts =data
    );
    console.log(this.workouts);
    }
}
```

So the thing is, when i console log 'this.workouts' it returns 0, an empty array. Shouldn't there be all the records from the json file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `console.log()` code into the callback you pass to subscribe

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
    data=> {
      this.workouts =data;
      console.log(this.workouts);
    });
}
```

`fetchData` (observables) are async. The function you pass to subscribe is executed when data becomes available.

Comment: Ok, but if i want to work with the workouts array on another page, every time i want info from the array i have call the subscribe?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681 is what you want.