# Subscribe to another subscription in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a private method which i use for authentication. Then i have another method (public) that i call in my components called `login` to do the actual login. I want to be able to subscribe to the `login` method which in reality subscribe's to the private `authentication` method so that i can show loading and other messages while login in being performed differently for each view. Is it possible?

**Authentication method:**

```
private userAuthenticate( email: string, password: string ) {
    return this.httpPost(`${this.baseApiUrl}/auth?format=json&provider=login`, {userName: email, password: password}).subscribe(
        res     => this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken),
        err     => this.logError(err),
        ()      => console.log("Authentication done.")
    );
}
```

**Login method:**

```
login( email: string, password: string ) {
    this.logout();
    return this.userAuthenticate(email, password);
}
```

I want to subscribe to the **login** method so that i can control my loaders and error messages etc.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't subscribe to `Subscription` (returned by `subscribe()`). You can only subscribe to `Observable`.

To get an `Observable` use `map()` instead of `subscribe()`. Then the caller of `login()` can do the subscription.

```
private userAuthenticate( email: string, password: string ) {
    return this.httpPost(
             `${this.baseApiUrl}/auth?format=json&provider=login`, 
             {userName: email, password: password}
           )
           .map(res => this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken));
}
```

For the other callabacks, if your really need them, you can use the `catch` and `finally` operators.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow make it work both ways, for instance calling `login` method activates the subscription automatically if not hooked? Like `login.subscribe()` in some cases and `login()` in some (which would default to previous method). If not then guess i might need to make two separate methods `$login` and `login`

Comment: Difficult to say without more understanding why you want to do that but it sounds like an additional method that just calls `userAuthenticate().subscribe()` might do what you want. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681 might also be related.

Comment: When you say use `catch` and `finally`, you mean in the `userAuthenticate` method right?

Comment: Yes, in case you still want to handle errors and completion there, even when `subscribe()` isn't used there anymore.

Comment: Basically i just want two ways to be able to login. (1) Global error and loaders are used in view. (2) I provide local error and loader containers.