# Undefined global variable but showing in view of Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am confused with my codes in Angular 2. In my `ts` file I have:

```
    import { Test } from '../../../../models/test';
    import { TestService } from '../../../../services/test.service';
    import { Job} from '../../../../models/job';
    import { JobService } from '../../../../services/job.service';

    export class TestTakeMcComponent implements OnInit {
          company_name: string;
          test: Test;
          job: Job;

          constructor(
            private testService: TestService,
            private jobService: JobService
          ) { }
          ngOnInit() {
            this.getTest();
            this.getJob(this.test.id);
          }
          getTest(){
            this.testService.getById(40).subscribe(
              test => {
               if(test.data.data.length != 0){
                 this.test = test.data.data[0];
               }
              }
            );
          }
         getJob(id: number){
           this.jobService.getJobByTestId(id).subscribe();
         }
    }
```

And in my HTML file I have:

```
<h3 class="box-title">{{ test?.title }} </h3>
```

Surely, the data binding `{{ test?.title }}` is working and showing the data. But during the call of another function `getJob(this.test.id)` on my `ts` file, it says an undefined parameter.
How this became undefined when it is showing perfectly in the view? I wanted to use the data inside `this.test` variable to other functions but I cannot since it is undefined.
Please someone has the same issue with me and how did you fix this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `console.log()` is executed before `this.test` gets a value assigned. The execution is async, which means it scheduled to run later, while the execution of the sync code continues immediately.

`{{ test?.title }}` is `undefined` first but updated later, but the change happens too fast for a human too recognize.

If you move the `console.log()` you'll see the value

```ts
      getTest(){
        this.testService.getById(40).subscribe(
          test => {
           if(test.data.data.length != 0){
             this.test = test.data.data[0];
             console.log(this.test);
           }
          }
        );
      }
```

**update**

```ts
export class TestTakeMcComponent implements OnInit {
      company_name: string;
      test: Test;
      job: Job;

      constructor(
        private testService: TestService,
        private jobService: JobService
      ) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getTest().subscribe(val => 
            this.getJob(this.test.id));
      }
      getTest(){
        // add `return` and replace `subscribe` by `map`
        return this.testService.getById(40).map(
          test => {
           if(test.data.data.length != 0){
             this.test = test.data.data[0];
           }
          }
        );
      }
     getJob(id: number){
       this.jobService.getJobByTestId(id).subscribe();
     }
}
```

Comment: but for example I will create another function using another service,
`getJob(){
this.jobService.getJobByTestId(this.test.id).subscribe();
}`
the call of this function will return an undefined parameter. That is my problem. It will not store the data globally in `this.test` variable.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code and how you use it. Perhaps the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681 give you some idea how to work with observables. There are also several tutorials out about how to use observables (with or without Angular)

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to chain async calls, otherwise the order of execution will probably not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Replace you code with this :

```
import { Test } from '../../../../models/test';
    import { TestService } from '../../../../services/test.service';

    export class TestTakeMcComponent implements OnInit {
          company_name: string;
          test: Test;

          constructor(
            private testService: TestService
          ) { }
          ngOnInit() {
            this.getTest();
            // console.log(this.test);
          }
          getTest(){
            this.testService.getById(40).subscribe(
              test => {
               if(test.data.data.length != 0){
                 this.test = test.data.data[0];
                 console.log(this.test);
                 this.getJob();
               }
              }
            );
          }

          getJob(){ 
              this.jobService.getJobByTestId(this.test.id).subscribe(); 
         }
    }
```

You have just put the `console.log()` at wrong place.

As `this.testService.getById(40).subscribe` is async part , so

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTest();
    // at this time we'll not have this.test ;
    // console.log(this.test);
}
```

Comment: this also works like charm. but I have to select just 1 answer. But thanks anyway for another idea.