# how to run subscribe sequentially in observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, pipe, observable

I want to run code sequentially but I was wondering how this works, for example, I have a method that includes two observable and some fields. I want to run the first observable completely then the next field values check and after that the last observable method:

```
// first it should be run completely --Step1

ontemplateSelectChanged(e){
const api = 'api/Sales/SaleTemplate/' + e;
this.dataSourceService
      .generateCustomApiDataList('sales', 'SaleTemplate', api)
      .dataList$.subscribe(
        (data) => {
this.saleTemplateDsDto.saleTemplateDto = data.rows['saleTemplateDto'];
});
// 2nd this should be check --step 2
if (myCondition){
// a lot of code here
    alert("we are here")
    }
    // this should be run at the end. --step 3
     const additionApi =
            'api/Sales/Addition/List?$filter=AdditionCode eq ' +
            additionCodefilterValue;
          this.dataSourceService
            .generateCustomApiDataList('sales', 'Addition', additionApi)
            .dataList$.subscribe(
              (data) => {            
                additionDtoList = data.rows;})
    }
```

but at the current stage step 2 completed first and step 3 next and at the end step 1. and sometimes it works fine. I read about `concat` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366694/waiting-for-an-observable-to-finish), I know this is a nice feature to get what I need but to be honest I couldn't use it, and that only work if we have 2 observable over next each other(only step 3 and step 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough data to go around, but for a start you could use `tap` and `switchMap` operators. `tap` would be used for "step 2" and `switchMap` would be used to map to another observable (in your case "step 3", the 2nd HTTP request).

Try the following

```js
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ontemplateSelectChanged(e) {
  const api = 'api/Sales/SaleTemplate/' + e;
  this.dataSourceService
    .generateCustomApiDataList('sales', 'SaleTemplate', api)
    .dataList$
    .pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        this.saleTemplateDsDto.saleTemplateDto = data.rows['saleTemplateDto'];
        if (myCondition) {
          // a lot of code here
          alert("we are here")
        }
      }),
      switchMap(() => {
        const additionApi =
          'api/Sales/Addition/List?$filter=AdditionCode eq ' +
          additionCodefilterValue;
        return this.dataSourceService
          .generateCustomApiDataList('sales', 'Addition', additionApi)
          .dataList$;
      })
    ).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        additionDtoList = data.rows;
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing , I got that by switchMap we can unsubscribe from first request and by tap we can say what after, can't we? only one more tip . how about more than 3 step, for example in step 4  we have another obeserable or request. can we use switchMap with   3 or more request?

Comment: Yes you could keep piping additional operators as required. So if step 4 returns an observable, you could pipe in an additional `switchMap`.