# Angular Service Listen when data is Loaded from Server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observers

I've tried searching on google but couldn't find solution, So here is the problem:

I'm trying to load a data from server using `http` module in angular but the problem is that particular data is required by multiple components here is what i tried so far:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoreService {
    data: any = null;
    Event: Observable<Object>;     
    isLoadingData: boolean = false;

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
        if(!isNull(this.data)) { return observer.next({data:this.data, isBusy: isLoading}) }  // If Data is not null then return the data 

        if(this.isLoadingBaseDirectory) {
            return observer.next({data:this.isLoadingBaseDirectory, isBusy: this.isLoading}) // if http call is busy loading the data then return isBusy true
        }

        this.isLoading = true; // Data is empty and we are not loading data, then set isLoading flag to true
        this.httpService.get(`coreEnv/getPodiumBaseDirectory`).map((res:Response) => { return res.json() }).subscribe((data) => {
             this.data = data; // data load complete 
             this.isLoading = false;
             observer.next({data:this.data, isBusy: this.isLoading});
        })
    }
}

// Component ngOnInit Method:
this.isBusy = true; // Component Loading Flag
this.coreService.baseDirectoryEvent.subscribe((data) => {
  if(!data['isBusy']) {
    this.data = data['data'];
    this.isBusy = false;
  }
})
```

Now if i use above code in the multiple component and load them both in the same page, the second component does get the response `isBusy` flag `true` from the service because first component tried to load the data which sets `isBusy` flag to `true` in the service, but when service successfully loaded the data from server it does not trigger last `observer.next` for second component but first component get the data.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer i'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Günter Zöchbauer mentioned in his comment that to achieve this functionality see answer: [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681)

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using routing? If so, you could define a component-less parent route with a resolver. The resolver can get the data and all of the children can then access that data.

I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the `APM-Final` folder. Check out the product-resolver.service.ts.

Any route that is a child of this parent route can then access the data using syntax similar to this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.parent.data.subscribe(data => {
        this.product = data['product'];
    });
}
```

This is using subscribe on the data property because in my example the data could be re-retrieved with different parameters.