# Checking if an array of observables completed without firing them

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I create observables from HTTP requests in Angular 2. I want to run a piece of code if all observables complete without error.

Right now I'm using forkJoin to combine my array of observables

```
Observable.forkJoin(observables)
.subscribe(
  success => {
 //code
 },
 error => console.log('error'));
}
```

The issue I'm having is that forkJoin fires those HTTP-requests again. I already fired them when I created the observable, subscribed to it and put in an array. Is there an equivalent to forkJoin where I can run a piece of code after all observables complete, without firing the HTTP-requests again?

Comment: You could chain them using [flatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md#rxobservableprototypeflatmapselector-resultselector)

Comment: Or use [.do](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md) instead of .forkJoin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you subscribe to those `observables` twice but, as they are **cold observables** they get fired twice.

In order to prevent this, I suggest you follow this thread that addresses this problem [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)