# Angular - Possible Race Condition with - `publish().refCount()`?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

I've read an [*article*](https://netbasal.com/angular-stop-using-observable-when-you-should-use-a-promise-8da0788a8d2) which shows an example of 3 async subscriptions  to an HTTP request.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>{{ (person | async)?.id   }}</p>
      <p>{{ (person | async)?.title   }}</p>
      <p>{{ (person | async)?.body   }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.person = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
     .map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

*I already know that there is no need for an async here and that ReplaySubject can be used and that there are many other solutions , but that's not what I'm after.*

The author said that  :

> The current solution that people suggest:
>
> `this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
>        .map(res => res.json()).share()` ( which is `publish().refCount().`)

**Question:**

But re-thinking about `publish().refCount()` -  is it possible that (for some reason) :

- The first `(person | async)` has executed the request (refcount=1) and response came back *before(!)* the last two `(person | async)`'s  subscribed? - this will cause another http request(s) ?  I mean  - who guarantees that the 3 subscriptions will be available *concurrently* so that they will all share the same result? is there a possibility for race condition? *because i've heard that refcount() is subject to race condition.*
- Besides , When is it considered to be "`refcount()>0`" ? it that value checked when http is *being invoked* or is it being checked when response arrives ?

In other words -

`sub1` causes `refcount()=1` (invoking http). But meanwhile `sub2`( a second subscription) is made :

```
  sub1 ———————A—————> http invoked    
   <—————————B———————response
```

Looking at `A` & `B` stages :

When will `refcount()` will be `2` ? is it on stage  `A`  ( before/while http executed) or will subscriptions at stage `B` will also be considered as `refcount()=2` ?

Comment: Perhaps `publishReplay` is what you're looking for (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756526/217408)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi thanks, Yeah I know that I can use the last value (via publish replay , or replaysubject/behaviour subject) - But I'm trying to understand if there's a race condition  here  + when do refcount is calculated .

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge on Rx. Perhaps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question indeed. But I think there are no race condition involved in this piece of code.

The thing is, all the subscription are done **synchronously** in the template with the `async` function. 
Which means, the request will be fired when the first subscription is done indeed, but in the case the server respond before all the other subscriptions are done (if it is even possible), then the main thread will be occupied thus not firing another request when the next `subscribe` arrives.

Here is a little example I made that tries to reproduce that use case.

```js
const timer = Rx.Observable.of("value")
  .do(() => console.log("start request"))
  .delay(1)
  .do(() => console.log("end request"))
  .publish().refCount()

console.time("sub");
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("subscribe" + i)
  timer.subscribe()
}
console.timeEnd("sub")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Here I simulate a request that is responded in `1ms` by the server but all the subscriptions take (on my computer at least) around `10ms` to complete. So you could say that the response arrives before the subscriptions are all done.

As you can see in the log, the request is fired only once :)

Comment: I don't understand the test. The loop time is not exceeding the 1 sec

Comment: Oh, `delay` is taking a number of milliseconds, not seconds. So here it's a delay of `1ms` :)

Comment: Re-reading your test , I don't understand wht it suppose to show , of course that there will be only one request becuase the source emits only one event. so ?

Comment: There will always be one emission. I did some testing and all subscribers _untill emission_ will be counted. That source ( yours and http) was born to emit only one value forever. so I don't understand how I thought to myself that there 's gonna be another request for later subscrivers.