# Angular 2/4 Caching Data across application

Tags: angular

What is the best way to store/share application data across the application? I have a bunch of drop-down list that won't change very often but if they do I would reload them so I don't have to hit my web api unless the data is changed every.

Should I just create shared application service and store the data inside the service? I'm just wondering what the best practices are for this or what others are doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681 might be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a service makes total sense.

If I add a small thing, I would make the data Observable using RxJs.

Here is the guide you can refer to https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services

Comment: yes that's what I was thinking, should i use a Subject in a SharedApplicationService?

Comment: @Fab Sure, Subject or BehaviorSubject would do fine. But make sure you hide it from outside of class though. Expose only `Observable` by doing `return subjectItem.asObservable()`