# Return async value from a custom pipe: Angular4

Tags: angular

I have created a custom pipe for my application which takes the user id as an argument and returns the user name. For getting all the users I'm making an api call. Therefore, I want to run the loop after I get the users list from the api. I'm doing something like this:

```
 transform(userId: number): any {
  this.userInfoService.getUsers().subscribe(
    data => {
       this.allUsers = data;
       for(let user of this.allUser) { 
        if(user.id === userId) {
         return user.userName;
        }
       }
      return null;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error');
    })
}
```

But I'm not seeing any value on the UI when I'm using this pipe. The issue I'm suspecting is the value getting returned asynchronously. Any suggestions how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

I added a `return` and changed `subscribe` to `map`

```
 transform(userId: number): any {
  return this.userInfoService.getUsers().map(
    data => {
       this.allUsers = data;
       for(let user of this.allUser) { 
        if(user.id === userId) {
         return user.userName;
        }
       }
      return null;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error');
    })
}
```

then use it with the async pipe

```
{{userId | myPipe | async}}
```

Comment: that works like a charm! But, is there any other solution that doesn't make the api call everytime I'm converting userId to userName? Because if I have a long list of userIds in *ngFor, its making the api call for each userId.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "every time I'm converting userId to userName". You could use a shared service that caches the results. This might help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681