# HTTP response caching and nexting in BehaviourSubject in AngularJS 2/4

Tags: angular, http, rxjs5

I have 2 sibling component having a service which has HTTP call to render a json. 
OnInit, the Component B fetches the HTTP response calling the service and loads the screen.
The click event on the Component A, should make the component B to refresh its data.

I followed the answer posted by ObjectiveTC from -> [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/46558833#46558833)

```
    _docdata: BehaviorSubject<DetailSection[]> = new BehaviorSubject<DetailSection[]>([]);

service.getData(){return  this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res) =>{this._docdata = (res.json()); console.log("1st return"); return this._docdata; })     
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error|| 'Server error'));  }
```

This worked fine.

```
refresh(){
this.http.get("../../assets/reqd-detail.json")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((data:Array<DetailSection>) => this._docdata.next(data));
}
```

> getting error --> ERROR TypeError: _this._docdata.next is not a
>   function
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (detail.service.ts:156)
>       at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub
>   (Subscriber.js:238)
>       at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:185)
>       at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:125)
>       at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your map function you are overriding the _docData to an response object(that is of type Array) not as observable. And that does not have next function on it.

Try this

```
_docdata: BehaviorSubject<DetailSection[]>;

service.getData(){return  this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res) =>{
             let detailSections = res.json();
             this._docdata = new BehaviorSubject<DetailSection[]>(detailSections); 
             console.log("1st return"); 
             return detailSections; })     
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error|| 'Server error'));  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
But i am getting error for _docdata.next() in the refresh() method
Error => ERROR TypeError: _this._docdata.next is not a function

Comment: Yes the reason you were getting error in refresh because in getData you initialized _docData with an object not with BehaviourSubject. Did you try the above code?

Comment: Now refresh() worked fine. But getData() is not rendering the response.

refresh (){
return this.http.get("../../assets/reqd-detail.json")  
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe((data:DetailSection[]) =>{ this._docdata.next(data);console.log(this._docdata)},
  (err: any) => console.error("fetch: ERROR",err),
  () => console.log("fetch: always"));
}

Comment: Are you using getData directly or through _docData?

Comment: It should return the value as we are returning whatever response coming from get in addition to assigning it to _docData. Did you copy the entire code specially the last line return detailSections?

Comment: Yes copied the entire code.
I am using getData() through _docdata

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked fine for me.

- Subject variables

  _docdata: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  docdata: Observable =   this._docdata.asObservable();

  getData() / refresh () { return  this.http.get(this.url)
         .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe((data:DetailSection[]) =>{ this._docdata.next(data);console.log(this._docdata)},
          (err: any) => console.error("fetch: ERROR",err),
          () => console.log("fetch: always"));}
- Fetched the response in the Components as :

  this.detailService.getPageData(key,srcFrom);
          this.detailService.docdata.subscribe((dataList) => {this.dataList = dataList;console.log("dataList from component",this.dataList);});