# cache management for angular services

Tags: angular, caching, design-patterns

When managing cached data in services we face many issues caused by the fact that we work with two different databases (the real database on back-end, the cached data in front). since cache in some services are refreshed independently (more/less frequently) than others, this creates data incoherence (eg: a component that uses a service that has a more updated data than another)

Is theire any design patterns that would guide us to handle cache in angular services whith efficiency (without incoherence) ?

Comment: use an "interceptor" and clear cache when you updated or insert data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681

Comment: We use observable in shared service and wherever required would subscribe to this.