# TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have an Ionic app that has a `user` provider with a `signup()` method:

```js
doSignup() {
  // set login to same as email
  this.account.login = this.account.email;
  // Attempt to login in through our User service
  this.user.signup(this.account).subscribe((resp) => {
    this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
  }, (err) => {
    //console.log('error in signup', err);
    // ^^ results in 'You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected'
    //this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);

    // Unable to sign up
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: this.signupErrorString,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
  });
}
```

For some reason, this code never calls the success callback, only the error handler. When it does, it results in the error you see in the comment above.

My `user.signup()` method looks as follows:

```js
signup(accountInfo: any) {
  return this.api.post('register', accountInfo).share();
}
```

My `Api` class looks as follows:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Api is a generic REST Api handler. Set your API url first.
 */
@Injectable()
export class Api {
  public static API_URL: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(endpoint: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    if (!reqOpts) {
      reqOpts = {
        params: new HttpParams()
      };
    }

    // Support easy query params for GET requests
    if (params) {
      reqOpts.params = new HttpParams();
      for (let k in params) {
        reqOpts.params.set(k, params[k]);
      }
    }

    return this.http.get(Api.API_URL + '/' + endpoint, reqOpts);
  }

  post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    return this.http.post(Api.API_URL + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts);
  }

  put(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    return this.http.put(Api.API_URL + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts);
  }

  delete(endpoint: string, reqOpts?: any) {
    return this.http.delete(Api.API_URL + '/' + endpoint, reqOpts);
  }

  patch(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    return this.http.put(Api.API_URL + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts);
  }
}
```

I tried removing `share()` from `user.signup()`, and returning `Observable<any>`, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Where are you call doSignup() ? Perhaps 'this' isn't available in that context.

Comment: It's called from `<form (submit)="doSignup()">` in my signup.html: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/ionic-jhipster-starter/blob/master/src/pages/signup/signup.html. signup.ts is here: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/ionic-jhipster-starter/blob/master/src/pages/signup/signup.ts

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I faced this issue when creating a new project using generator-jhipster-ionic (yo jhipster-ionic giving v3.1.2), following [Matt Raible](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65681/matt-raible)'s (OP) [Use Ionic for JHipster to Create Mobile Apps with OIDC Authentication](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/01/30/jhipster-ionic-with-oidc-authentication) blog article, but choosing JWT authentication instead of OIDC.

The origin of the issue was a mix of problems.

I had the issue when running a Ionic app with the livereload server, CORS issues happening and Angular HTTP returning the classic `HTTP failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`, where 0 is the HTTP error code.
However, in the current case the issue was hidden by bad error handling at the Observable level.

When you follow [Angular's HttpClient #Error Details](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) section advices, and add an Observable pipe with a catchError operator on the HTTP POST call, you can get the proper HTTP error details. In this case, instead of going down to the `rxjs/util/subscribeToResult.js:71` ([TS source #L80](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/stable/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L80)) `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected` default error case, it goes to `rx/util/subscribeToResult.js:23` ([TS source #L34](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/stable/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L34)), and the error is handled properly in the piped method.

After following the Observable calls, I found that the current default authentication interceptor, as seen in this template [src/providers/auth/auth-interceptor.ts](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic/blob/master/generators/app/templates/src/providers/auth/auth-interceptor.ts) catches HTTP error 401 and does nothing for the others, basically muting them and preventing their propagation.

**TL;DR** In the JWT case, the solution is to simply remove the `src/providers/auth/auth-interceptor.ts` `.catch(...)` block, allowing error propagation to `login.service.ts`, and in its `this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe((data) => { ... }, (err) => { ... })` error callback.

I believe the issue and solution could be the same for your OIDC case, its signup method, and error callback.

[Edit] Even more since the same `.catch` code can be found in the starter example mentioned in the first post comments: [ionic-jhipster-starter - auth-interceptor.ts#L31](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/ionic-jhipster-starter/blob/304356f93964c35bca81dbaa0be008ae2c852040/src/providers/auth/auth-interceptor.ts#L31)

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane! This solved my issue. I did have to use Sid's workaround below as well since JHipster returns a 201 with "Created" in the body when registration succeeds.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped!
On a side note, I don't understand why you use `.share()`, in the current case... It should mainly be used when you need real asynchronous behaviour, transferring ownership from the subscription caller to the data source, expecting multiple events to happen from it along its lifetime, and in order to use automatic ref-counted cleanup and source re-construction when subscribers come after all previous subscribers have left. 
With an HTTP call like here, I understand you may not want the HTTP call not to block, but asynchronous may seem overkill...

Comment: I understand you may want multiple simultaneous service subscribers and response caching with replay (like in [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r)), but I'm just not sure about the current use cases (starter project and jhipster-ionic generator).
Maybe nice features are to be expected/demonstrated in a future version?

Comment: thanks, although my problem was different, but removing catch block from the interceptor allowed me to reach the actual error.

Comment: In my case I simply wasn't returning an observable at all.. (~_~) ...I had the observable return commented out (-_-,) in my getStuff() method.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I was returing with empty return:

```
if (...)
   return; // problem here
```

To fix, I returned the observed object:

```
if (...)
   return req.next();
```

Comment: in my case, I didn't return outcome as observable and fixed by using`of(null)` or `mapTo(null)`

Answer (score 7):

For me, I had a subscription piped with `takeUntil` like this:

```
this.route.queryParams
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
  .subscribe(async(queryParams) => {
  });
```

I forgot to initialize `this.ngUnsubscribe` with an observable. When I set the value to an observable in the component (`ngUnsubscribe = new Subject()`), the error was gone.

Answer (score 5):

I did face this issue and in my case `responseType` suppose to be `text` (because of designed API end-point) rather than default `json`.

`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Before:

```
getToken(tokenCommand) {
    return this.http.post(API_BASE_URL + 'user/token', tokenCommand);
}
```

After fixed:

```
getToken(tokenCommand) {
    return this.http.post(API_BASE_URL + 'user/token', tokenCommand
                                                     , { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

I think this error message is too general and it will be nice if it's developers could provide more detail/helpful error message. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sid! This helped me arrive at the solution. I had to do the following (because of TypeScript I suspect): `signup(accountInfo: any) {
    return this.api.post('register', accountInfo, { responseType: 'text' as 'text' }).share();
  }`

Comment: Awesome! your solution helped me (Y). I also think the same "I think this error message is too general and it will be nice if it's developers could provide more detail/helpful error message"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and typical scenario was that I was returning different actions based on certain condition. But handling of one condition was missing and I was not returning anything under my effects. That's when this issue came up. It's always better to have a default return action to avoid such instances.

```
...mergeMap((res: FetchWorkflowStatusResponse) => {
   if(this){
      return action1
   } else if(that){
      return action2
   }
}
```

Now if some value other than `this` and `that` comes then there will not be any `return` statement and the error will be thrown.

Comment: You can use backticks (\`) to mark inline code or triple backticks to mark code blocks

Answer (score 3):

I was using **ngrx** with **Angular** to store the token. I faced this error in my `interceptor.ts`.

The wrong code was this:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this._store
            .pipe(
                select(fromSelectors.selectAuth),
            )
            .subscribe((state: fromReducers.AuthState) => {

                if (state.token != null) {
                    const clonedReq = req.clone({
                        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + state.token)
                    });
                    return next.handle(clonedReq);
                }
                else {
                    this.router.navigate(['login']);
                }
            });
    }
```

I fixed the code by returning the flow:

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return this._store
            .pipe(
                select(fromSelectors.selectAuth),
                switchMap((state: fromReducers.AuthState) => {

                    if (state.token != null) {
                        const clonedReq = req.clone({
                            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + state.token)
                        });
                        return next.handle(clonedReq);
                    }
                    else {
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                        // return EMPTY stream
                        return of({}) as Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
                    }
                })
            );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved here the right way :)

I have been facing this issue when trying to authenticate a user using JSON Web Token. in my case it's related to authentication interceptor.

Sending a request to authenticate a user doesn't have to provide a token since it doesn't exist yet.

Check that your interceptor include this:

```
if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True")
            return next.handle(req.clone());
```

And that you provide `{'No-Auth':'True'}` to your header's request like this:

```
  authenticateUser(user): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'No-Auth':'True'});
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiEndpoint}/auth/authenticate`, user, {headers: headers});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by a different problem.

I was providing the service in two different points. I had written:

```
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
```

and I was also providing the module in the `app.module.ts`. So if you encountered this error you can check this before going ahead

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me doing unit-test on watch mode.
Stop the build, trigger it again = the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was neglecting to return an Action in my NgRx Effect. I had a conditional statement which was only returning an Action on one condition.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by a different problem.

I was providing the service in two different points. I had written:

@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
and I was also providing the module in the app.module.ts. So if you encountered this error you can check this before going ahead

Answer (score 0):

For me, I met this because I was upgrading ngrx to 13 and rxjs to 7. Old code blocks are

```
let actions$
// other codes

provideMockActions(()=>actions$)
```

And I fixed it by

```
let actions$ = new ReplaySubject()
// other codes

provideMockActions(()=>actions$)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I forgot to import `HttpClientModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while working on my Ionic app and it turned out to be a null pointer in the service class where I was trying to read and write from session storage. It is unclear why the error shown wasn't more specific, but I believe that the thing reporting the error, the subscription in the component, was covering up the underlying error with its complaint about expecting a stream.
I was trying to do:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('someItem', someObject.itemValue);
```

In my case someObject was now null because of a change I had made (but forgot to update the setItem call).
After fixing that null reference, my "stream" error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Request needs to handled at last.

For interceptor, you need to throw error or handle it your way. eg:

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      this._auth.logout();
      return throwError(error);  // <==========  do somethig at the end to your request
    } else if (error.status === 500) {
      this._swalAlertService.error('Oopss! looks like server issue.');
      return throwError(error); // <==========  do somethig at the end to your
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my interceptor.ts

Old code

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              const url = this.remoteApi + this.refreshTokenRoute;
              if(url === request.url){
                this.clear();
                this.router.navigateByUrl('');
                return throwError(error);
              }
              else{
                return this.refreshToken(request, next).pipe(
                  switchMap(() => {
                    const authReq = request.clone({
                      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.localStorage.getToken().token),
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                  })
                );
              }
            }
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

New code

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              const url = this.remoteApi + this.refreshTokenRoute;
              if(url === request.url){
                this.clear();
                this.router.navigateByUrl('');
                return throwError(error);
              }
              else{
                return this.refreshToken(request, next).pipe(
                  switchMap(() => {
                    const authReq = request.clone({
                      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.localStorage.getToken().token),
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                  })
                );
              }
            }
            else{
              return next.handle(request);
            }
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

My problem was that I did not return the status if the error is not equal to 401

add for other request return next.handle(request);