# TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream

Tags: angular, google-api, gmail-api

I’m developing an Angular 6 application which attempts to connect to the Google API and retrieve email messages.

I’m using this link as a guide:

> https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#examples

According to that site, the endpoint to get messages is:

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id

I’m not sure what my user ID is or what the mail message IDs are. So I just tried my email address for the user ID and 1 for the message ID (thinking it would just be incremental numbers).

However, when I send the request, I get this error:

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Note that I’m not using the gapi client library or any other library. I’m sending the request simply by HttpClient.request(req: HttpRequest). This is because we want to be able to send requests to multiple API providers, not just Google.

Here’s what the request looks like:

```
{
  body: null,
  headers: {
    headers: Map(0) {},
    lazyInit: {...},
    lazyUpdate: {
      0: {name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer ya29.Glv0B...},
      length: 1
    },
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
  },
  method: "GET",
  params: {...},
  reportProgress: false,
  responseType: "json",
  url: “https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/***@gmail.com/messages/1”,
  urlWithParams: “https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/***@gmail.com/messages/1”,
  withCredentials: false
}
```

Note that I’ve expanded the headers to show I have a bearer token which was not yet expired when I sent the request.

So my question is two-fold:

1) What does the error message mean: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.

2) How do I figure out my user ID and message ID?

EDIT: I came across a similar post here: [TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849258/typeerror-you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-expected). However, the solutions offered in that post did not solve my problem. Stephane provides a link on how to get the real error message (because the "You provided 'undefined' where a stream..." one is apparently not correct) at this site here: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details. Following that link, I wrote this:

```
async callEndpoint(endpoint: Endpoint): Promise<any> {
  const request = await this.getRequest(endpoint);
  return await this._http.request(request).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): ObservableInput<{}> {
  console.log('error in handleError:', error);
  return null;
}
```

But it doesn't even get to handleError. Instead it gives a different error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

^ I have no idea what that means.

A second reason the link doesn't answer my question is because my question is two-fold: besides asking why I'm getting the error I'm getting, I'm also asking how I can figure out what my gmail user ID is and what the message ID is. The error I'm getting *might* just be caused by that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849258/typeerror-you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-expected)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the real error by sending my request through postman:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
            "message": "Insufficient Permission"
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
}
```

Not sure why I have insufficient permissions. I have a valid not-yet-expired oauth2 token which I'm sending in the Authorization header. My guess is scopes.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is because you are not returning an observable when using the rxjs `catchError` operator. You should probably be using `throwError`, see: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError.

Here is an example of how to use `throwError` based on your code:

```js
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
  console.log('error in handleError:', error);
  return throwError(error);
}
```

As to why you are getting an HTTP error, it looks like you need to provide some kind of authorization, it should tell you how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Comment: Thanks for the help, Mike. throwError gives me the same error message: 'TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected'. The insufficient permissions error was because of the scope I provided in my oauth2 request. As soon as I supplied a greater scope, I was able to get the expect response at least in postman. It's still giving me the TypeError in my application though.

Comment: Hi Mike, I may have to post this in multiple comments since it won't all fit in one. Here is my code: callEndpoint(endpoint: Endpoint): Promise<any> {... this._http.request(request).pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        ).subscribe(result => { console.log('>>> result =', result); },
          error => { console.log('>>> error =', error); }); ... }   handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): ObservableInput<{}> {
    console.log('In handleError --> error =', error);
    return throwError(error);
  } Sorry it's so condensed but I don't know how to prettify it in a comment.

Comment: Anyway, the console.log in handleError prints out "In handleError --> error = TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable." This is followed by another console log: "err = TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable." <-- I believe this log comes indirectly from the throwError as I am catching and logging errors thrown from callEndpoint (not shown in the code above).

Comment: One other note: when I open my network tab in chrome, I see no traffic. It's like it's not even getting off the ground.