# Angular 5 ngIfElse: Storing conditional result in a variable

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

**Code:**

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]='{ rotate: !users }'>refresh</mat-icon>
<div *ngIf="usersObservable | async as users; else loading">
  ...
</div>
<ng-template #loading let-users>
  Waiting...
</ng-template>
```

**Expected:** `rotate` class applied to `<mat-icon>` while users are loading

**Result:** class not applied

**Question:** Is it possible to store/use boolean result of ngIfElse evaluation?

**P.S.:** In this example, I want `rotate` class to be applied to `<mat-icon>` until HTTP request completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `as users` variable is only in scope for bindings on or inside the tag where the `*ngIf` is applied.

You'd do something like

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]='{ rotate: !(usersObservable | async)?.users }'>refresh</mat-icon>
```

Ensure your observable behaves properly when subscribed to more than once.
For example some of the methods mentioned in [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. But it's interesting for me - is there a better way to do this? I mean without using AsyncPipe twice.

Comment: You can do the subscribing in code and assign the response to a field in `subscribe(...)` and bind to that field instead.

Comment: What Is the difference in efficiency between these two ways? (if it exists)

Comment: Depends on how you implement it. Using explicit `subscribe()` is less likely to get wrong to cause 2 server requests instead of 1. If done right, I wouldn't expect a notable difference.