# rxjs http request is not cached

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to understand rxjs `publishReplay`, `refCount` and `share`
What I wanted to achieve was caching of a http request as described here [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r/36296015#36296015)

Here's what I came up with

```
export class TestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://httpbin.org/anything').map((data: any) => {
    console.log('getting data');

      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
  } 
}
```

calling it

```
t.getData().subscribe((data: any) => console.log(data));
t.getData().subscribe((data: any) => console.log(data));
```

the request will usually made twice.

Just to unterstand the cause of this:

**Am I correct that this behavior occurs if the observable (http request) hasn't completed yet when I subscribe a second time?**

If I move the seccond `t.getData()` inside the the first subscriptions next only one request is mode.

[here is a stackblitz with the code](https://angular-piv8cb.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call the method `getData()` it is returning a new observable - it doesn't matter that you've converted a cold observable to a hot one.

A more appropriate use of `.publishReplay` is to keep the same instance of the Observable.

For example:

```
export class TestService {
  data: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.data = this.getData();
  }
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://httpbin.org/anything').map((data: any) =>{
    console.log('getting data');

      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
  } 
}
```

Calling it:

```
this.data.subscribe(t=> ...);
this.data.subscribe(t=> ...);
```