# RxJS subscribing to the observable in two different files

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am new to RxJS and I am trying to subscribe to an observable function in two different and I am wondering if there is a way to trigger a call from one of the functions can also change the outcome in the second file.

I have an action creator and authGuard subscribe to my loginService and I am trying the action creator will trigger once I call the login function from the auth guard.

action.js

```
    this.loginService.handleLogin(userId)
      .subscribe((data) => {
         console.log("response in action.js", response);
      },
      (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

authGuard.js

```
    this.loginService.handleLogin(userId)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log("response in authGuard.js", response);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log("error", err);
      })
```

loginService.js

```
    handleLogin(userId) {
      const url = `api/user/${userId}`;
      return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers })
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          return Observable.throw(e);
        });
    }
```

expectation:

I am expecting to get console.logs results in action.js and authGuard.js when I call handlLogin function of loginService from either file.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call handleLogin, a separate observable is being created and returned.  So your two files are not subscribed to the same object.

Take a look at the answers here for how to structure your handleLogin implementation to fix this: [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r).  Note in particular this answer about `shareReplay()` which is probably the better up to date answer though it's not the highest scored: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43943217/518955

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP observable makes an HTTP request for each subscriber. To share a single HTTP request for multiple observers, you need something like the [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) operator.

```
   export class FetchService {
    data$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(){
        this.data$ = this._http.request(this._url)
            .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
            .catch(this.errorHandler)
            .share();
    }

    getData(){
        return this.data$;
    }
}
```

Now the multiple observers will share the same observable.

> This operator is a specialization of publish which creates a
>   subscription when the number of observers goes from zero to one, then
>   shares that subscription with all subsequent observers until the
>   number of observers returns to zero, at which point the subscription
>   is disposed.