# How to send data to a subscriber without using a HTTP method?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have this code in my app:

```
  public requestList(): Observable<Record[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.requestUrl)
      .map((response: any) => this.currentList = response.json())
      .catch(this.setError);
  }
```

I wish this list was loaded only once from my backend. So I need to check if the `currentList` is fulled. If so, I must ignore the `http.get()` and manually return `currentList` contents to the subscriber, transparently as if he was getting it from the backend. How can I achieve that?

```
  public requestList(): Observable<Record[]> {
    if (this.currentList !== undefined) {
      // MAGIC HERE: returning content that's already in this.currentList HOW?
    }
    return this.http.get(this.requestUrl)
      .map((response: any) => this.currentList = response.json())
      .catch(this.setError);
  }
```

Comment: Magic: `return Observable.of(this.currentList);`

Comment: Thank you very much! Are you interested in writing an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I'm writing one with more detail.

Comment: No need. This solves my problem as it is. It's just to point you positive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static `of` operator to create an observable that emits the provided value (or values in sequence if you pass multiple arguments) and then completes.

Example:

```
...
if (this.currentList !== undefined) {
  return Observable.of(this.currentList);
}
...
```

Here are some docs on it: [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-of), [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html)

Also it may be more appropriate to use the `do/tap` operator to modify the state of something outside of the stream since you aren't really intending to return a different value from `map`.

Example:

```
...
return this.http.get(this.requestUrl)
  .do((response: any) => this.currentList = response.json())
...
```

Here are some docs on it: [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)

#### Edit:

Found another post which is similar that deals with avoiding duplicate in-flight requests but also addresses caching. So for some more discussion on the topic you may want to check it out:
[What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r)