# how to fetch data from server first time only in angular?

Tags: angular, ngrx

can you please tell me how to fetch data from server first time only  and show to  screen . but if user come again or if component again loaded it get data from store .I am using redux with ngrx .

I made a sample application in which i have two button `home screen`
and `new screen` home screen I show list which is coming from `server` .when i click `new screen` button and come back to home screen it again it server and get the data.I don't want to hit again.I want to get data from `store` .How i will get it

here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoqhee?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.ts)

(don't open this link in chrome stackblitz have issue in chrome )

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

 products$: Observable<Product[]>;
  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
              private store: Store<fromApp.ProductState>,
              private router : Router
              ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new productActions.Load());
    this.products$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getProducts))
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r)

Comment: this is not dublicate Question

Comment: That's not a useful assertion. Why not? What did you learn from reading that question and what do you still want to know? Did you try it? What are the specifics of your situation that prevented it from working? [Edit] the question.

Comment: first they are not using `ngrx` or store .secondly how I will check data is present on store or not

Comment: 1. Does that matter? You're talking about caching the server data, it doesn't necessarily matter where that does within the app. 2. I'd imagine the relevant documentation tells you how to check whether something is in the store.

Comment: i got the answer thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, I would probably have a property inside my store that indicates whether the data was already loaded or not, e.g. `loaded`. The first time you dispatch the action that goes and fetches the data in your Effect, when the data returns you would also set this `loaded` property to `true`. The default value would be `false`. Inside your Effect you could then use `withLatestFrom` and select the `loaded` property. If it's set to `true`, don't do anything, if it's set to `false`, go and fetch the data.

First of all, change your `ProductState` and introduce a `loaded` property:

```
export interface ProductState {
  toggleCheckBox: boolean,
  products: Product[],
  loaded: boolean;
  error: string
}

const initialState: ProductState = {
  toggleCheckBox: true,
  products: [],
  loaded: false,
  error: ''
};
```

In your reducer, on `LoadSuccess`, set the `loaded` property to `true`:

```
case ProductActionTypes.LoadSuccess:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: [...action.payload],
    loaded: true,
    error: ''
  }
```

Now, inside your Effect, check for the `loaded` property and then fetch the data depending on its value:

```
@Effect()
loadProduct$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
  ofType(productAction.ProductActionTypes.Load),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getLoaded))),
  switchMap(([, loaded]) => {
    if (loaded) {
      return empty();
    }

    return this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
      map((products) => {
        return new productAction.LoadSuccess(products)
      }),
      catchError(err => of(new productAction.LoadFail(err)))
    )
  })
);
```

This means, your Effect would only fetch the data when it's not loaded already, which is indicated by the `loaded` property on your `ProductState`.

Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wglqco?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct.effect.ts) to see it in action. Open up the Network tab the dev console to verify that the request is only fired once and after that it's being "cached" due to the `loaded` property.

Comment: Nice, like this answer and helped me, I did find however that using `filter` after `withLatestFrom` was a better solution, and I got errors returning `empty()` so removed that, other than that great job