# RxJS To Cache Http Result

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs

Im in the process of migrating an Angular v1.4 app to v5 (hopefully v6 in the new year).

The app has a number of components for example, header, tabs, grids, images, authentication etc etc.

Each component makes particular `http.get` to get system and user preferences, and caches the result to avoid the app making multiple of the same http.get.

Looks like RxJS is a powerful library and have it available to use. Its seems there are many examples, methods and views of achieving this cacheing with RxJS.

Wanted to share what i have done in my v5 app and get feedback. Inspecting the app in DevTools, it seems only 1 http.get is performed, so seems like it works..

systemPreferences.service.ts:

```
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

export class SystemPreferences {
    private $cache: Observable<Object>

    private requestConfig() {
         return this.http.get("www.someurl.com").pipe(
             map(response => response.value)
         );
    }

    public getPreferences() {
        if (!this.cache$) {
            this.cache$ = this.requestConfig().pipe(
             shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
            );
        }

        return this.cache$;
    }
}
```

header.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.systemPreferences.getPreferences()
        .subscribe(
            (result: any) => {
                this.headerTitle = result.title || '';
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('there has been an error');
            },
            () => // Some completion code
        );
}
```

Same component code for routingGuard canActivate, tabs etc etc

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is that i dont know if this is the correct 'rxjs' way to perform caching?

Comment: Yeah basically it is. Just be aware that you should add `take(1)` after `shareReplay` because otherwise the Observable won't complete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-http-network-call-in-r)