# nested observables executed one after the other after termination

Tags: angular, rxjs

i'am implementing angular solution to get all items in database first , after termination i then get the current selected box from database , then mapping the items to the box.
i need that all the items are charged then getting the box at the end do the mapping ,
i have the following code that works but it s a litle bit dirty by doing a nested observables , any one of you have a cleaner solution??
i found on the documentation the solution os swithMap but i think that it is not appropriate to my case because a switch map does not work the upper observable to finish to execute the inner one

```
this.getItems().subscribe(items => {
        this.itemsInDataBase = items;
    this.loadActiveBox().subscribe(box => {
        this.selectedBox= box;

        this.selectedBox?.versions.forEach((version, index) => {
            this.itemsInDataBase.forEach((itemInDatabase, index) => {
                version.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                        this.insertItemInbox(item, itemInDatabase, version);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
```

grazie mille

Comment: If you want to add an order to your calls, `concatMap` would be a viable option, see https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

Comment: with concat map i have to add delays , i thing that it is not that clean.

Comment: The only delay I could see here is concatMap waiting for your outer observables to finish. Which you're doing right now anyway, so I wouldn't see a problem there. Anyway, in the meantime Michael's posted a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS `switchMap` operator could be used where the inner observable *depends* on the outer observable. In your case, since both observables appear to be independent, you could use the `forkJoin` function.

```js
forkJoin({
  items: this.getItems(),
  box: this.loadActiveBox()
}).pipe(
  tap({
    next: ({items, box}) => {
      this.itemsInDataBase = items;     // <-- are these needed?
      this.selectedBox = box;
    }
  })
).subscribe({
  next: ({items, box}) => {
    box?.versions.forEach(version =>
      items.forEach(itemInDatabase =>
        version.items.forEach(item =>
          this.insertItemInbox(item, itemInDatabase, version)
        )
      )
    )
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: the two observables are dependent , i have to get all my items first then execute the second observable.

Comment: @Ares: Does the HTTP request `this.loadActiveBox()` depend on the response from the `this.getItems()` request? Note that I am asking about the request. Not what is done with their responses.

Comment: the requests are independant but the responses yes, i understand what you mean.

Comment: If the requests are independent then you could use the `forkJoin` function. Other than that I don't understand the question quite clearly.

Comment: i have an extra question , i want to execute the first observable only once and then use it every time .then i execute it in the constructor and pass a reference to fork join, is it correct??

Comment: @Ares: Better way to share the response from the observable is to use `shareReplay` operator. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36271899/6513921) for more information about it.